# filter many2one field with multi condition domain odoo-12

Tags: python, odoo

I want to filter serial_no according to device_model and product_qty of serial_no != 0.
my code:

```
class EmployeeCustody(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.custody'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    device_model = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Device Model', required=True)
    serial_no = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', string='Serial Number',
                                domain="[('product_id', '=', device_model),('product_qty', '!=', 0)]")


class ProductionLot(models.Model):
    _name = 'stock.production.lot'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', 'Product', required=True)
    product_qty = fields.Float('Quantity', default=0)
```

I got serial_no according to device_model but with all quantities( I don't want quantity = 0)

Comment: The default value of a `Float` field is `0.0`, the condition will not work if `product_qty` is redefined else where as a non-stored computed field.

Comment: all values of product_qty are 0 or 1. it doesn't have none value.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the value of Float field is None

So you can try

`domain=['&',('product_id', '=', device_model),('product_qty', 'not in', (0, None))]`

or

`product_qty = fields.Float('Quantity', default=0)`

Hope it can help because I'm unable to test my solution

Comment: another thing, `'&'` is default in domain, so you can remove it in this case

Comment: @CuongNmtm You can see at [Relational fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields) that domain could be a string and there is an example at [Account/partner.py#402](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/partner.py#L402)

Comment: @Kenly Ok I see, they use string for domain that include variables